# Fastest way to convert JSON date to ISO 8601 in c#

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid

I am using c# asp.net with angularJS.
In the controller of the ASP.NET I retrieve data from the model.

```
public JsonResult Employee_GetList()
        {
            List<EmployeeModels> List = obj.Employee_GetList();
            return Json(List, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And in the angular controller I used this code to get this JSON data:

```
$scope.getEmployees = function () {
    $scope.start();
    viewModelHelper.apiGet('Employee/Employee_GetList', null,
        function (result) {               
            var data = result.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length ; i++) {
                if (result.data[i]['enter_date'] != null) {
                    var date = new Date(parseInt(result.data[i]['enter_date'].substr(6)));
                    data[i]['enter_date'] = $filter('date')(date, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
                }
            }
            $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
        });
    $scope.complete();
}
```

So like you see I need to make a loop to convert all the "enter_date"s from JSON date to a string so I can use it in my grid 
and that process takes so much time with the huge data I am dealing with...
Is there anyway faster than this to convert the "enter_date" from JSON date to string or ISO 8601  format ???

Comment: Your controller method should return a 'view model'.  This model should be in the ideal format for the view.  If that involves modifying the format of the data returned from a data store to be in a 'better' format for the view, then that's where you do it.  Also, I suspect, you are returning a huge data set because your EmployeeModel contains things that the view will never show.  A view model will allow you to only pass the fields you need.

Comment: Agreeing to @Neil. So if you don't want to play with the date in angularjs and want to just display them you should return a formatted string the way you like to display instead of DateTime from c#.